# Git pre-push issue no such file or directory

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm using github for windows with git-lfs, committed the changes to the local branch which were done successfully, then gave an error after i tried to sync to the remote. 
Trying pushing my changes from the git shell and this error came up

> error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-push: No such file or directory
>   error: waitpid for .git/hooks/pre-push failed: No child processes

I then pushed by

> git push --no-verify

it did get pushed but I tried downloading the files and they gave a 404 error.
Any change that i commit gives the same error of the pre-push hook.

Answer (score 23):

Found the solution. 
Deleted the pre-push hook in the .git/hooks folder 
Installed git lfs again. Issue was fixed.

Comment: This helps me.Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Run `git lfs update --force` to override corrupted hooks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the hook was in windows `wsl` with a non-existent shebang. A symlink using `ln -s` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the directory separation character in `core.hooksPath` to get rid of that error.

So e.g. in `~/.gitconfig` I changed

```
[core]
   hooksPath = "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\MyHooks"
```

to

```
[core]
   hooksPath = "//c/Users/MyUser/MyHooks"
```